# .Net MVC 3 Telerik DropDownList not firing event OnChange

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik

I have a `DropDownList` which has a bind to a `ViewData` which populates the list perfectly.

I would like to commit the user selection when "OnChange" event fires. But I am struggling
to make it work, in fact nothing happen.

```
<fieldset style="width: 300px;">
                        <legend>Change Vehicle</legend>

                            @{Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
                            .Name("UpdateVehicleTypeNumbers")
                            .BindTo((IEnumerable<DropDownItem>)ViewData["PlantItemsDropDown"])
                            .Enable(true)
                            .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("submitVehicle"))
                            .HtmlAttributes(
                                    new { @id = "vehicle"})
                            .Render(); 
                            }

                    </fieldset>
```

I think the error might be in theJavaScript code.

```
   function submitVehicle(){       
        window.location = '../Operator/GPS?jobId=' + @the_job_id + '&vehicleId=' + $("#vehicle").val();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
apparently Telerik elements can be accessed with the name convention: `tElementName`
in my case the following code worked:

```
function submitVehicle(){       
        var veh = $("#UpdateVehicleTypeNumbers").data("tDropDownList").value();
        //etc
```